# Multiple image rollover in javascript with for loop

Tags: javascript

Please help me. I want to do the below activity in javascript programming with the help of "for loop".

Suppose there are five images on the web page. When I rollover the 1st image, the text should display "it's a first image". When I rollover the 2nd image, the text should display "it's a second image". When I rollover the 3rd image, the text should display it's a third image.

I have tried and it's successful but it's manual. I am new in Javascript programming..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style_latest.css" type="text/css"> 
<title>MATHERAN TRIP</title>


<style>

#displayText
{
    width:413px;
    height:auto;
    background-color:#666666;
    color:white;

}
#displayText1
{
    padding-left:5px;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>

<img src="images/img1.jpg" id="img1" onmouseover="clickEvent1()" onmouseout="imgRollout()" width="100" height="100">
<img src="images/img2.jpg" id="img2" onmouseover="clickEvent2()" onmouseout="imgRollout()" width="100" height="100">
<img src="images/img3.jpg" id="img3" onmouseover="clickEvent3()" onmouseout="imgRollout()" width="100" height="100">
<img src="images/img4.jpg" id="img4" onmouseover="clickEvent4()" onmouseout="imgRollout()" width="100" height="100"><br/>

<div id="displayText">
<span id="displayText1"></span>
</div>

<script>
var myData=new Array("Hi, How r u?", "Hey, whats up? Hey, whats up? Hey, whats up? Hey, whats up? Hey, whats up? Hey, whats up?", "Hello, whats going on?", "Hi friends")

document.getElementById("displayText").style.visibility='hidden';


function clickEvent1()
{   
    document.getElementById("displayText1").innerHTML=myData[0];
    document.getElementById("displayText").style.visibility='visible';
}

function clickEvent2()
{   
    document.getElementById("displayText1").innerHTML=myData[1];
    document.getElementById("displayText").style.visibility='visible';
}

function clickEvent3()
{   
    document.getElementById("displayText1").innerHTML=myData[2];
    document.getElementById("displayText").style.visibility='visible';
}

function clickEvent4()
{   
    document.getElementById("displayText1").innerHTML=myData[3];
    document.getElementById("displayText").style.visibility='visible';
}

function imgRollout()
{
    document.getElementById("displayText").style.visibility='hidden';
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What have  you tried?

Comment: I have tried manual as I am new in Javascript.

Comment: that means I have done without for loop...

Comment: Please help me to look into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you *don't* include inline event attributes at each element. But I would consider including an inline html5 `data-` attribute with the message associated with the elements:

```
<img src="images/img1.jpg" data-msg="Hi, How r u?" width="100" height="100">
<!-- etc -->
```

Then you can bind the same rollover functions to each element using a loop as follows:

```
function doMouseOver(e) {
    document.getElementById("displayText1").innerHTML =
                                    e.target.getAttribute("data-msg");
    document.getElementById("displayText").style.visibility='visible';
}
function doMouseOut() {
    document.getElementById("displayText").style.visibility='hidden';
}

var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img"),
    i;
for (i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
    imgs[i].addEventListener("mouseover", doMouseOver);
    imgs[i].addEventListener("mouseout", doMouseOut);
}
```

Within the `doMouseOver()` function, the `e` argument is the `event` object, and thus `e.target` gives you a reference to the element the event happened to - so then you can retrieve the particular `data-msg` value for that element to display it.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3c7Rb/

Having said that, **you don't need the loop** either. You can bind the functions directly to the `document`, and then within the mouse over handler you simply test whether the target element has the `msg-data` attribute. If it does, display it, otherwise do nothing:

```
function doMouseOver(e) {
    var msg = e.target.getAttribute("data-msg");
    if (msg) {
        document.getElementById("displayText1").innerHTML= msg;
        document.getElementById("displayText").style.visibility='visible';
    }
}
function doMouseOut() {
    document.getElementById("displayText").style.visibility='hidden';
}

document.addEventListener("mouseover", doMouseOver);
document.addEventListener("mouseout", doMouseOut);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3c7Rb/1/